# "Error: Error serializing .customerId returned from getServerSideProps in "/pricing"

Tags: javascript, next.js, async-await

I keep trying to call an api from my getServerSideProps function in my Next.js application, but everytime I try to do so I get this error

"Error: Error serializing `.customerId` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/pricing".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value."
[image]

This is the code for the Pricing page

```
const Pricing = ({customerId}) => {
  console.log(customerId, 'Customerid Pricing')
  return(
    <div>
      <ProductDisplay customerId={customerId}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  //create customer variable
  let customerId
  // Create authenticated Supabase Client
  const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient(ctx)
  // get the user session from supabase
  const { data: { session }, } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
  //get the user email from the session
  const email = session.user.email


  //create stripe customer
  const createCustomer = async () => {
    let createdCustomer;
    let customerAvailable;
    
    try {
      const checkCustomer = await stripe.customers.search({
        query: `email: '${email}'`
      })  
      
      createdCustomer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkCustomer))
      customerAvailable = createdCustomer.data
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      
    }
    
    if (customerAvailable.length) {
      customerId = createdCustomer.data[0].id
    } else {
        try {
          const res = await fetch('/api/create-customer', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              email
            })
          }) 

          const newCustomer = await res.json();
          customerId = newCustomer.customer.id

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error) 
        }
      }

  }

  if (session) {
    createCustomer()
      
  } else {
      return{
        redirect: {
            destination: '/signin',
            permanent: false,
        }
      }
    }

  return {
    props: {
      customerId
    },
  }
}

export default Pricing;
```

This is the `/api/create-customer` the fetch function is trying to call

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    const {email} = req.body
    try {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email: email
        });
        res.status(200).json({
            code: 'customer_created',
            customer,
        })

        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({
            code: 'customer_creation_failed',
            error: error
        })
        
    }
};


export default handler;
```

please help me, thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think you ever actually declare the `customerId` variable that you return in page `props`.

Comment: I declared it in the getServerSideProps here

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
  //create customer variable
  let customerId
  // Create authenticated Supabase Client
  const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient(ctx)

```

Comment: Yes, but `let` variables are [block scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). You never define a value at the top-level, so its undefined when you return it in the page `props`. You need to refactor your code to ensure you set the expected value in the same scope as your return statement.

Comment: You need to `await` for the promise returned by `createCustomer()` to resolve, e.g. ```if (session) { await createCustomer() }```. When `getServerSideProps` returns the promise still hasn't resolved so `customerId` will not be defined.

Comment: Just to reinforce what @juliomalves says above: you're not waiting for `createCustomer()` so you end up returning props before it sets the value of `customerId`.